# JVM cannot load class properly

Tags: java, class, exception, jvm, classloader

Inside Class A, I have a method and in the method, there is a line:
someClassB.staticMethodB(arg); where someClassB is another class.
Now, arg is fine.
But at this line I get an error:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: someClassC

It seems that someClassB does not load properly for the static method staticMethodB to execute.

But inside someClassB, we are not using someClassC at all.
So why JVM tries to find someClassC?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect you're *either* actually using it in `someClassB` somewhere you haven't seen, or it's used in a *superclass* of `someClassB`. Either way, it sounds like you need `someClassC` to be present...

Comment: Yes...it is used in superclass.